# Turkey crown cooked to temperature but pink juices after resting

Tags: food-safety, turkey

I cooked a boneless 1.8kg Turkey crown at 170C (340F) fan for 90 minutes with foil on top to protect the skin from burning. I removed the foil and cooked uncovered for another 30 minutes, this brought the internal temperature to just under 70C (160F). As a precaution, I cooked the crown for a further 30 minutes, bringing the internal temperature up to 72-75C where I probed. The meat has been left to rest wrapped in foil before being refrigerated for consumption the next day. This should bring the meat up to > 75C (165F).

When I went to place it in the refrigerator, the juices on the plate were slightly pink.

Will this be safe to eat cold or if I reheat the slices in a stock to 75C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The color of the “juices” is not an exact indicator of whether food was cooked to/held at a safe temperature. If the thermometer is  accurate and was properly placed, then that’s what you should trust.

Comment: Anecdotally, I can say that I regularly see poultry and pork have clear juices after resting after the oven, but the left-overs have slightly pink juices the next day. I don't know if there's a scientific explanation for why it happens though.